# How do I see aptitude "Search patterns"? (~n, ~i, ~U,..)

Tags: debian, aptitude, man

While opening `man aptitude` I see this in many places:

```
(see the section “Search Patterns” in the aptitude reference manual).
```

How do I open this reference manual? I want to find patterns like `~i` (search for installed packages), `~U` search for upgradeable packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [online version](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/), or offline in the `aptitude-doc-en` package that will put the docs in `/usr/share/doc/aptitude/html` (you also have for example `aptitude-doc-fr` for French documentation, and others).